# Seperating GraphQL schemas by model in Laravel App

Tags: laravel, model, graphql, lumen

I am pretty new to GraphQL. I know that you can define the schemas of your models in the schema.graphql file but I havent really found any best practices around that file. Do you typically store all of your models/mutations etc. in that one file? Or is there a way you can create a schema file for each model in your application?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I am using Lighthouse and after diving into their docs more I found that you can separate scheme files by model.

For example:

```
  |-- schema.graphql
  |-- post/
    |-- post.graphql
    |-- category.graphql
```

Then you can import those files in your main shema.graphql file using `#import post.graphql`

Comment: Link for reference for anyone with the same problem: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/digging-deeper/schema-organisation.html#schema-imports

Answer (score 0):

Tested this and it works so I figured I would post the answer here in case anyone else come across this.

If you are using Lighthouse for your Laravel & GraphQL integration you can separate your model's schemas by nesting the file structure like so:

```
|-- schema.graphql
  |-- post/
    |-- post.graphql
    |-- category.graphql
```

From here you can import any of the existing schema files you have by using `#import post.graphql`.

Another thing to note is that the `schema.graphql` is where all of the initial `/graphql` requests go first, so you will have to import your other schemas within that file.

Link for reference: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/digging-deeper/schema-organisation.html#schema-imports